# Get content of <section> tag including html tags and store it in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following stripped down part of some html code:

```
<section id ="test" contenteditable="true" ... >
    <h3> This is a header </h3>
    <p> Some stuff in here </p>
    <p> Some more stuff here </p>
</section>
```

How do I get the `<h3> and <p>` elements from the section and store it in a variable?

E.g.

```
var result = "<h3> This is a header </h3> <p> Some stuff in here </p> <p> Some more stuff here </p>"
```

Also is it possible to get linebreaks etc as well?

I've tried using jquery `.val()` and JS `document.getElementByID(..)`, but they both return the section element altogether.

Comment: use $('#test').html()  or document.getElementByID('test').innerHTML,

Comment: @jQuery Thank you Mr. jQuery, works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  jquery

```
var result = $('#test').html();
```

or javascript

```
var result = document.getElementByid('test').innerHTML;
```

Comment: @Arunprasanth: I think you're wrong, but I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: May be you will get your answer on this link??www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

Comment: @Arunprasanth: it works for me, once your typo (`getElementByID` is changed to `getElementById`) is corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o05wo8k4/2/ although I'd typically use an alternate approach to bind the click event-handler: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o05wo8k4/1/

Comment: @DavidThomas ow sorry , simple but big mistake , thanks for correcting me , i didn't notice the incorrect syntax, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#test').html()
```

also check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4b2xoL5/1/)